# What is the net magnetic flux density in the center of a four-pole stator and other multiple-pole stator?

Tags: ac-motor, stator

[image: two-pole stator with magnetic field produced by each pair of windings]

[According to this ppt](http://www.ee.hacettepe.edu.tr/%7Eusezen/eem473/ac_machinery_fundamentals-1p.pdf),
if the currents are given as
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
i_{aa'}=I_M\sin{(\omega t)} \\
i_{bb'}=I_M\sin{(\omega t-120°)} \\
i_{cc'}=I_M\sin{(\omega t-240°)} \\
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
the net magnetic flux density in the center of the two-pole stator will be
$$\vec B_{net}=\vec B_{aa'}+\vec B_{bb'}+\vec B_{cc'}=...=1.5B_M(\sin{(\omega t)}\hat x-\cos{(\omega t)}\hat y)$$

[image: four-pole stator]

However, there was no similar formula given for the four-pole situation. I searched online but I couldn't find any source that mentions it.
Personally, I think \$\vec B_{net}=\vec 0\$, since all B cancel out.
If I'm right, how would this four-pole stator make the rotor inside to rotate?
If I'm wrong, what are the detailed steps that lead you to the result? The answer I'm expecting is in the vector form:
$$\vec B_{net}=...\hat x+...\hat y)$$
Further question: what about the cases with more poles?

Comment: So net flux for the two pole stator is a vector rotating through 360 degrees.  A magnetic field that rotates and pulls the rotor.  If your net flux went to 0 for the four pole stator, the rotor would stop, so that is wrong.  Four pole stator will have two magnetic vectors at right angles to each other.  6 poles, 3 at 60 degrees.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Would you please show the calculation? I want to know what the B_net looks like mathematically.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat (This comment is to clarify my previous comment.) Would you please show the calculation? Since you mentioned that there are `two magnetic vectors at right angles`, I want to know what the B_net_1 and B_net_2 looks like mathematically.

Comment: If I knew it, I would supply it.  But have never considered it beyond basic theory.